# Visual Studio 2017 code colors not working correctly

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Can someone tell my why my code isn't being colored on the left side? I get that this isn't a huge problem but as a rookie programmer its a nice way of confirmation.

note that both of these code snippets are in the same unity project/VS solution but in different scripts for testing purposes.

[image]

Comment: Is autocomplete of Unity API working?

Comment: Probably intellisense, has still not finished scanning all the files.

Comment: @Programmer Autocomplete is working, but indeed it does not show me any unity related stuff

Comment: Ok See **Fix Part 4:** from the answer in the duplicate question. Do that on the particular file/script that is having that issue.

Comment: The problem might be from the fact that the left Update() method is not inside a class.

Comment: @DanielFintinariu it is, but that isn't visible in the screenshot

Comment: Inherits from MonoBehaviour? :)

Comment: @DanielFintinariu yes. But at the right side where the colors are shown correctly it does color monobehaviour orange as well, while at the left it doesn't. But the answer was given in the duplicate question